# How to attach a notebook to a question?

Tags: discussion

As I have posted a number of times, I am still learning how to do things here. I was wondering if someone could help me to figure out how to attach a notebook file to a question.

Comment: This is unfortunately not possible.  You can host the notebook on another site through, and post a link here.  You can use services such as Dropbox, Google Drive, http://ge.tt/, etc.   However, the best thing would be if you could write the question concisely and include all the relevant code (and *only* the relevant code) within the question.

Comment: When people post notebooks, oftentimes they leave a lot of irrelevant code in there, or don't take the effort to isolate the problem.  Please don't do that.  Of course there are cases when a problem is best illustrated with a notebook, but I think this is the case only in a minority of situations.  To take [your last question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/113931/12) as an example, if you illustrated it with an actual equation (which would have been helpful), the best thing would have been to use a *single* simple one.  The fact that you had 6 is irrelevant to the question.

Comment: Don't. 

Prepare a minimal example and post that. Then the question is answerable even by folks reading it on a cellphone. 

Moreover, notebooks are not safe, one can hide dynamic code, events etc. in many places there. I'm not opening notebooks/enabling dynamics unless I really trust the source.

Comment: Thank you all. I will do better. I appreciate all of your patience and helpfulness. I will redo the question on the ode fitting.