# Ask Question - Large amount of numbers

Tags: support

I am new in StackExchange. I would like to ask a question in Mathematica Stack Exchange about a code I am writing. I would need to write in the question a table of data which is long. Is it possible to do it?
I'm sorry if this is a stupid question but I am having problems orientating myself.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is probably answered as well as it presently can be in these:

- [What is a good way to make sample data points available in a question?](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1936/121)
- [Upload large amount of data more easily](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1351/121)